# Filtering Sylius Grid on associated object attributes

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have a grid of a `Label` Sylius resource. In this grid, I show the Label's User denomination (a `Label` object is associated to the `User` object).
I would like to be able to filter my objects with this `user.denomination` field. Is there a way to do that ?
I found this pull request https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/5501#discussion-diff-70548106 and if I understand the title, it has be done to do that, but viewing the submit code and testing things, I don't succeed to have something working.

I tried that :

```
filters:
    denomination:
        type: string
        options:
            fields: ['customer.denomination']
```

but it tries to get the customer.denomination attribute of my Label table. Any idea of how to do that ?

Tks everyone !

EDIT : 
Here is my new code :

```
filters:
            customer:
                type: string
                label: labellisation.search.structure_label
                form_options:
                    type: contains
                options:
                    fields: [customer.denomination, customer.description]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the grid config, driver options, I needed a repository method that get the customer. So I have now

```
 driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: LabelBundle\Entity\Labellisation
                    repository:
                        method: createListQueryBuilder
```

and my createListQueryBuilder returns a queryBuilder that get the customer data.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here in the Orders grid for instance](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/grids/order.yml#L82).

It should work, on dev-master I suppose. Maybe the apostrophes are redundant?

Comment: I have this exception : `'customer' is not defined` : `QueryException: SELECT o FROM LabelBundle\Entity\Labellisation o WHERE customer.denomination LIKE '%héros%' OR customer.description LIKE '%héros%' ORDER BY o.date asc  +`
I have removed the apostrophes, and I do have a customer in my Labellisation object

Comment: In the Orders grid, the db query do a left join with the customer table. This is what it is missing in my query. But I didn't see anything in the ordres grid code that indicate the grid it needs to join the customer table...

Comment: Are you sure your mapping is okay? And your db schema is up to date?

Comment: Yep ! I needed to set a custom repo method that gets my customer